# Moving from Nvidia to AMD in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, games, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I currently use a Nvidia GTX 650 ti and the nvidia drivers (v.387.22) which are pretty much working "out of the box" I just selected them from the "additional drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates" graphical interface and everything works fine.

I watch 4k movies, I play OpenGL and **Vulkan** games (among them AAA high demanding 3D accelerated games ) without any issue (in terms of stability and graphical quality) but at a **low** frame-rate.

So I decided to upgrade to a RX 580 8GB which will arrive to my home tomorrow.

My question is: How to do a proper swap of the video cards? (should I purge the existing nvidia driver first? How to remove every related file and/or graphical setting like I would using DDU in windows?)

Which AMD driver and overlay (I dont know even what overlays are but searching on goole I found out they exist for AMD drivers) should I download to have **best performance in 3d games especially** in **Vulkan**.

Do I have to **reinstall** **Vulkan** or does it come with the driver and/or the overlay?

Is the process straight forward as with the nvidia drivers or do I have to manually install the drivers? if I do then from where? can I set a PPA and have them update automatically?

I use ubuntu 17.10 my kenrel version is 4.13.0.17 and I use the gnome shell v. 3.26.2

The rest of my hardware is AMD FX8320, Asrock 970 Pro3, 16GB DDR3 ram.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the Nvidia drivers and that can be easily done with `sudo apt purge nvidia` . Drivers for AMD are already included and there are no alternatives. Hopefully it will just work but if you ask me, not a good idea to use AMD with Linux at this moment. It would be better to upgrade to a better and newer Nvidia.

Comment: @MichaelBay I found so many different stuff like AMDGPU/AMDGPU-PRO/MESA/fglrx. Will the computer boot just by placing the card?because I dont have igpu. Also are you sure that just purging nvidia will delete all the possible conflicts?I ask this because I purged apps in the past(like VLC or VirtualBox)but later when reinstalling them found out that some settings and related files remained even after the purge. Last but not least why would you say that AMD is not good with linux at the moment? I thought the opposite would be true since even Torvalds essentially hates nvidia for being so closed.

Comment: It doesn't conflict anyway. Purging Nvidia drivers is just routine cleanup. If there's no Nividia graphics there's no point in keeping the drivers (and you asked about it). Yes, the command I gave will remove everything. Drivers are not apps. Purging some software often does not remove the hidden configuration files in your user. About AMD that's just my opinion and was provided "as is", not to elicit debate, but neither my opinion nor Linus' really matters anyway. What matters is the system requirements of the games you intend to play.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yea michael I know that but it seems that there are more issues with AMD cards and I just learned about them today so I am in desperate need for articulated opinions/guides from people that game with a  RX4xx or newer card since as far as I googled today I see many issues raising which indicate that the AMD cards do not perform well in linux (compared to their nvidia counterparts) System requirements is just a shallow borderline merely there to validate compatibility.. they mean nothing if for example Ill game at 30 FPS on 1080p playing Dawn of War (while it should be 60+)